# the quake 2 md2 file format (theory)

Tags: c++, c, opengl

i am trying to load md2 files in opengl but i noticed that most example programs just use a

precompiled list of normals. something like this.....

```
//table of precalculated normals  
{ -0.525731f,  0.000000f,  0.850651f },   
{ -0.442863f,  0.238856f,  0.864188f },   
{ -0.295242f,  0.000000f,  0.955423f },   
{ -0.309017f,  0.500000f,  0.809017f },   
...  
...
```

Ok this may sound abit dumb, but i thought each model is made of different triangles, how then is it possible that you can use one set of precompiled normals to render all models?
It seems abit strange and any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a precompiled table of normals, and use a lookup table to select one that is 'good enough' for a particular case. Each triangle is on a distinct plane, and it's that plane that has a normal, not the triangle itself.

For instance, lets imagine we have a point. Expand that point into a sphere for the purposes of this discussion, makes it a little easier to grasp conceptually. If you draw a perfect circle around that sphere on the `y` axis, then rotate that circle in the `x` axis 1 degree each time, you'll end up with 360 circles. If you take a normal at 1 degree intervals along each of those circles, you'll end up with `360  ** 2` points. From there, your normal is the vector from the center of the sphere to that point on the sphere, and it is a normal for a plane constructed tangential to point on the sphere. What you end up with if you calculate these two for every point on that sphere is a precalculated table of normals, which will almost certainly be good enough for most situations. Now you just need to design a lookup scheme for that data (plane -> normal).

Comment: Do you happen to have any literature i can go through on this?

Comment: No, sorry, this is just off the top of my head and my understanding of the math involved.

Comment: Most higher level math books that cover 3d geometry should probably cover it though.

Comment: +1. That's what I've heard. The table covers a finite subset of the unit sphere. So, instead of storing normals in .md2 you would store indices to save space (That's what vector quantization is about).

Answer (score 6):

It's been answered already but I want to shed some more light on it.

The table contains vectors that cover the unit sphere's surface pretty uniformly. It seems the set of 162 vectors are the corners of a [subdivided](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation) [icosahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedron). This is done to lossily compress 3D vectors of unit length to an index (8 bits), see [vector quantization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_quantization). For storing an arbitrary normal vector you can search the table for the closest match and store the index of this match instead. With this table of 162 well distributed vectors the angle between the original vector and the approximated one is expected to be below 11° which seems to be good enough for the Quake2 engine.

Answer (score 2):

The [MD2 file format](http://tfc.duke.free.fr/coding/md2-specs-en.html) specifies that each vertex has a "normal index", and this is a lookup into a [well-known table of normals](http://tfc.duke.free.fr/coding/src/anorms.h). I would assume that these normals are distributed around a sphere. Presumably, the tool that built the model chose the most appropriate of these normals for each vertex.

With regard to the first answer: if you want a very faceted model (like a cube), then each polygon does indeed have its own normal, and each of the vertices that makes up that polygon should use the same normal vector. However, if you want smooth shading (such as a torso), it's common for each vertex in a polygon to have a different normal vector. This allows the lighting to vary across the polygon, which is useful in both per-vertex and per-pixel lighting scenarios.

Comment: If you are talking about vertex normals, then you still aren't talking about the polygon itself having a normal. You are still talking about a plane having a normal, and that plane is usually taken to be a plane constructed perpendicular to the intended curvature of the shape at the point that the vertex occurs.

Comment: I was just trying to clarify the point that I think you were making in your first paragraph. When it comes to MD2 models, I think it's more useful to consider the tangent plane at each vertex, rather than the tangent plane for each triangle (which is the way I read your answer at first). From your comment on my answer, I think we're on the same page.

Comment: I've done enough graphics work to be dangerous, but not enough to know all that much. I just happen to be strong enough in the maths to figure out what's going on. The first paragraph was an attempt to answer the question as I percieved it was asked. As an aside, the normals of the plane the polygon itself is on isn't useless, it's just not used in lighting (it might be used ie, in a physics engine though, or collision detection, or...).

Comment: Though you will use the polygon plane normal for lighting if you are drawing flat-shaded polygons.